# Chapter counting set up

Tags: numbering, chapters, counters

I want chapter numbering like:
Chapter 1, Chapter 2, Chapter 3, Appendix A, Appendix B.

But I am getting like: 
Chapter 1, Chapter 2, Chapter 3, Appendix D, Appendix E.

When appendix chapters are started I give command like:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\chapter{}
```

If I use `\setcounter{chapter}{1}` then the generated `.pdf` file got `hyperref` problems.

Can anybody suggest what should be the easiest way to do what I like? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\refstepcounter{chapter}`?

Comment: Well, for sure, since the chapter number 1 is doubled

Comment: `\setcounter{chapter}{1}` will lead to a start of `Appendix B, Appendix C` etc.

Comment: Can you tell us which document class you are using?  Usually you should be using `\appendix` to make the numbering switch.

Comment: @AndrewSwann documentclass is report

Answer (score 3):

The `\appendix` command is better suited for this, but it could be achieved without it as well.

The resetting of the chapter counter at the beginning of the appendix confuses `hyperref`, so `hypertexnames=false` option is necessary, to provide correct link anchors.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Three}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}%
\chapter{First Appendix}
\chapter{Second Appendix}
\end{document}
```